# How to convert between different scala collections?

Tags: scala

When I google scala conversions everything is about converting java classes to scala.
How do you convert between scala collections in general? Like arrays to vectors, or maps (key,value pairs) to other collections, iterators to collections, etc? For example in C++ you can use `static_cast`. Is there a similar function in scala and how does it work? Or do you just have to memorize a ton of specific methods like toArray, toFloat, etc?

Comment: If what you want is, say, a `List` then remembering `.toList` really isn't much of a mnemonic challenge.

Comment: Also, you've got your general purpose `to` which takes a type argument, so `to[List]` should suffice as well

Comment: how does the to[] work, is it a trait? which classes implement it and to which other classes?

Comment: "how does the to[] work, is it a trait? which classes implement it and to which other classes?" – It would be helpful if you could explain which *precise* parts of the documentation of `to` are unclear to you, which parts you *do* understand and *don't* understand, what research you have done to clear up your understanding, and where, why, and how that research failed. That way, answerers a) don't waste time repeating things you already know, b) don't waste time repeating things you already tried and didn't work, c) can point out errors in the things you read during your research that lead …

Comment: … you astray. In addition to that, the Scala Developers can improve the documentation, so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems you had. Essentially, you you would make the world a better place, and who wouldn't want that? Oh, and also, if you have a new question, then please post it as a question, not as a comment.

Comment: Have you looked at the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/)?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes but searching "to" or even "to<>" will not really work cause there are so many "to"'s. I can't find the relevant "to<>"s.

Comment: You can just go to the type you have a look at which operations it provides, you can use the filtered search functionality it provides to look for the target type you want juts on that type.

Comment: @Thomas: Just search for `^to$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function like `static_cast` in Scala, but most collections support a `to<>` method for the popular conversions which names the result type (so nothing to memorize). The library is also more orthogonal than C++ so more operations can be done without converting to a different type.

One difficulty is defining `static_cast` in a type-safe way that only allows valid conversions. Scala does not have the concept of a "copy constructor", so this would require a typeclass that define all the valid type conversions, which would require a fair bit of code.

So this is possible but (presumably) not deemed useful enough to put in the standard library.